# RowFilter with special characters

Tags: c#, filtering, rowfilter

I have a table named myMainTable and I want to operate a .RowFilter on my DataView. For the moment my code is as such (the value used for the RowFilter is an example value):

```
var mainDataView = maindataDataSet.Tables["myMainTable"].DefaultView;
mainDataView .RowFilter = "LastName= '" + "Gemma O'Neil" + "'";
var mainDataTable = mainDataView.ToTable();
```

the problem I have of course is that it thinks (because of the ' in O'Neil) that the value I am looking for ends at "Gemma O".

How can I have it successfully apply the RowFilter for the full value "Gemma O'Neil" ?

Answer (score 0):

For circumstances such as this, you would simply need to escape the ' character; which for RowFilter is simply another ':

```
  string surname = "Gemma O'Neil";
  mainDataView .RowFilter = "LastName= '" + surname.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
```

(or, neater:

```
  string surname = "Gemma O'Neil";
  mainDataView.RowFilter =
        String.Format("LastName='{0}', surname.Replace("'", "''"));
```

)

Incidentally, this is a very similar problem to that faced by people trying to avoid SQL Injection attacks. If this is a new development then I'd recommend investigating Entity Framework and LINQ, which will handle this for you automatically.

Comment: Thank you. I thought '' would just implode the query altogether. Nice to know it just thinks of it as a single quote. Thanks! I'll have a look at LINQ as per your suggestion